Reference request for unitary Shimura varieties
Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and let $X$ be the Shimura variety associated to the unitary group $U(m,n)$ over $K$ (after a suitable choice of PEL datum).
Is there a reference that explains how to construct the complex points of these Shimura varieties in classical language? I've heard that $X$ can be written as a quotient of a complex unit ball by an arithmetic group, but I'd like to see a reference where this construction is written down.
